# ajax call is printing multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax

I tried to append HTML file into a div block using ajax call but its not working properly, as of now its firing multiple times.

**Jquery**

```
var url = $('#abResponse').val();
var $element = $('.responseEle');
console.log(url);
 if(url != undefined){
    url = url + "/jcr:content";
    url = url + ".html?text";
    console.log(url);
      $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(html) {
                console.log('success');
                $element.append(html);
                console.log('****************end**************************');
                break;
            },
            error : function(){
                console.log('error');
            }
     });

 }
```

Comment: i think you miss a bit of code before this one. When is this piece of code fired? What is the event binded to run it?

Comment: if this is not triggered more then once there is no reason for success function to run more then once.

Comment: actually, I'm parsing a HTML file as a argument into success method, its appending but again the page is reloading

Comment: We need the code you are using to fire the code you have provided. What is that code included in ? A "submit" event on a form ? A "change" event on #abResponse ?

Comment: @Katz, " #abResponse" its a external HTML file based on url values i'm fetching the file and inserting to ".responseEle".

Comment: I also tried $.get() method, its working fine but page is reloading automatically with a seconds